# How to convert UITextField input from String to Double?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I got an error message saying that I have to **add "from" in the Double(billTotalTextField.text ?? 0.0)**,

but then I got another error message saying that "**Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"?**

What is the reason for that?

How to convert the String input to Double?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var billTotalTextField: UITextField!
    
    let tipPercentage = 0
    var billTotal = 0.0
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func tipButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        billTotal = Double(from: billTotalTextField.text ?? 0.0)
        
        
        if sender.currentTitle == "0%"{
            let percentage0 = 0.0
            print(billTotal * percentage0)
        }else if sender.currentTitle == "10%"{
            let percentage10 = 0.1
            print(billTotal * percentage10)
        }else if sender.currentTitle == "20%"{
            let percentage20 = 0.2
            print(billTotal * percentage20)
        }
    

}

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mixed string and numeric values in one parameter so you need to make it the same type, like this:

```
billTotal = Double(billTotalTextField.text ?? "0.0") ?? 0.0
```

Or a bit more clear:

```
if let text = billTotalTextField.text {
   billTotal = Double(text) ?? 0.0
}
```

Comment: `UITextField` text property default value is an empty string. It will never return `nil`. Even if you set it to `nil` just before accessing its value it will return an empty string.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's true, however it's declared as an optional type starting from Swift 2 so I believe that's how it should be handled.

Comment: This is just to allow you to assign an optional string to the text property (no need to unwrap it).

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah, it might be the reason, but for me it just seems odd because you can have nil in `UILabel` text property but cannot in `UITextField`. Besides it doesn't seem to be documented (only that it sets to an empty string by default) so I'd rather keep it safe and handle it as a usual optional rather than use force unwrap, regardless of its behaviour under the hood.